# How to save unique score in each TableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, cell

I would like to save a score in a cell that I saved with Realm.

Here is an image of my program.

[image]

When I press the top left button, an alert pops up to add a new cell with a label. The cell is saved with realm and is displayed properly. Then on the cell, there is two buttons on each side which can add or subtract a number to the score under the label of the cell.

Now I want to save the score when I change it of each cell and if possible with realm too.

Here is where I want to save it :

```
class CellVC: UITableViewCell {
    var scorepts: Int = 0
    let realm = try! Realm()
    var infosScore: Results<ScoreInfos>?

    @IBAction func minusPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if scorepts != 0 {
             scorepts -= 1
        countScore.text = "\(scorepts)"
         
            // save the score of the this cell cell
        }
        
        }
    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: Any) {
       
        scorepts += 1
        countScore.text = "\(scorepts)"
       
        // save the score of this cell cell

    }
```

Then when it's saved, I need to load the cell scores when the view loads.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're thinking about this all wrong. You don't save a "cell". A cell is just a view for displaying state. You save _state_. The problem with your code is that you are not _setting_ state: you are modifying the cell but not the underlying state.

Comment: @matt super good comment. Let me get a little more specific to Realm; A tableView is often backed by an Array (a dataSource) that contains the data the tableView displays. When the text in a cell is modified, you'd actually be modifying the data in that array. In this case the dataSource is a Realm Results object (which behaves similar to an array). When + is clicked, obtain the corresponding object from Results (by index), enter a write transaction and update the object. The Results object will then contain the updated data; if it's being observed it can reload the cell or reload it manually.

Comment: @Jay Thanks, I don't know realm which is why I didn't actually give an answer. I was hoping someone would come along and add the relevant Realm info.